# Angular directive access value in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I read a directive value like the info attribute in the scope?

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <my-customer info="naomi"></my-customer>
  <hr>
  <my-customer info="igor"></my-customer>
</div>
```

For example with this controller:

```
angular.module('docsIsolateScopeDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    $scope.igor = { name: 'Igor', address: '123 Somewhere' };

    //can I read the info value?
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        customerInfo: '=info'
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-customer-iso.html'
    };
  });
```

You can find it on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EM6W6cGQr06WYkbk5hGx?p=preview), or similar in the angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To associate a controller with a directive, you can use the Directive Definition Object's `controller property`. Either specifying the controller as a function or specifying the name of the controller.

**Angular App**

```
angular.module('docsIsolateScopeDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$attrs', function($scope, $attrs) {
    $scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    $scope.igor = { name: 'Igor', address: '123 Somewhere' };
    //Here are the attrs values
    console.log($attrs.stars);
    console.log($attrs.info);
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
            starts: '=stars',
            info: '=info'
      },
      //Associate a controller
      controller: 'Controller',
      template: "Name: {{customerInfo.name}} Address: {{customerInfo.address}}"
    };
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <my-customer info="naomi" stars="star1"></my-customer>
  <hr>
  <my-customer info="igor" stars="star2"></my-customer>
</div>
```

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsIsolateScopeDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$attrs', function($scope, $attrs) {
    $scope.naomi = { name: 'Naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    $scope.igor = { name: 'Igor', address: '123 Somewhere' };
    //Here are the attr values
    console.log($attrs.stars);
    console.log($attrs.info);
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
            starts: '=stars',
            customerInfo: '=info'
      },
      //Associate controller
      controller: 'Controller',
      template: "Name: {{customerInfo.name}} Address: {{customerInfo.address}}"
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-directive-isolate-production</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="docsIsolateScopeDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
  <my-customer info="naomi" stars="star1"></my-customer>
  <hr>
  <my-customer info="igor" stars="star2"></my-customer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tested it? I get the errors for your first line "Unexpected token function" and "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]".

Comment: @NewDeveloper Wait for few minutes, let me give you full example

Comment: @NewDeveloper  check now, you can see in the console.

Comment: $scope.info is already used, so i changed it to $scope.attrsInfo = $attrs.info. You can see it on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EM6W6cGQr06WYkbk5hGx?p=preview). But the value of $scope.attrsInfo in the controller is undefinded.

Comment: @NewDeveloper check my answer, I've updated, it's working now, just replace the code.

Comment: @NewDeveloper I've updated my answer with update code, jsfiddle.

Comment: Isn't accessing isolated scopes through controllers beats the “isolation” purpose? Assuming that `naomi` and `igor` are $scope variables in _some_ controller, you should already have access to their scope, and with 2-way data binding you can actually change their properties through the directive and it'll bubble up back to the controller.

Comment: The module needs a custom string value, which should be entered in the html attribute and the controller needs to know the value, to process the selected data. The code from the user loading works for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As its name suggests, [isolated scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) are isolated, and that's why you can use 2-way binding - like you're doing with `customerInfo: '=info'`.

**When you make changes inside the `myCustomer` directive scope, it will bubble up in the scope hierarchy and will change the `users` object in your controller:**

```
angular.module('docsIsolateScopeDirective', [])
   .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.users = [{
           first_name: 'naomi',
           last_name: 'doe'
       },
       {
           first_name: 'igor',
           last_name: 'doe'
       }]
}])
```

And your template should look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <my-customer info="user"></my-customer>
    <hr>
</div>
```